# \autoref doesn't work correctly when used in tufte-book

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, tufte

i want to use the `\autoref` command (from the `hyperref` package) in the document-class `tufte-book`.

mini-example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Testsection}
\label{sec:test}

\begin{figure}
    \rule{20pt}{20pt}
    \caption{Testfigure}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

Cross Reference to \autoref{fig:test}

\end{document}
```

The Output is

> Cross Reference to section 1

and not

> Cross Reference to figure 1

what one could expect. any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: one ugly way to fix this is load `\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}` before the `hyperref` package. The problem seems to be that `tufte` and `hyperref` battle for supremacy. I'm sure a guru can explain the details :)

Comment: Did you try `\caption{Testfigure\label{fig:test}}`, i.e. putting the `\label` into the caption text?

Comment: makes no difference

Comment: @cmhughes Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 4):

One ugly way to fix this is load

```
 \usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
```

before the `hyperref` package. The problem seems to be that `tufte` and `hyperref` battle for supremacy.

Comment: Alas, this results in larger fonts used for the captions, and they're no longer done in the same justification style, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I have a somewhat elaborate patch for this, which works for my test cases (they are decidedly not thorough, though).  The problem ultimately boils down to the internal use of the `\@caption` macro.  I borrowed a patch idea from someone else (the link has escaped me already) and this two part patch is also not pretty, although you can put it into your `tufte-common-local.tex` file to keep it out of the way and avoid the need for `\makeatletter`.

(This also should really check whether hyperref was not disabled, in which case it could be put directly into the tufte-common.def file, if it doesn't have additional bugs.)

Here's the two-part patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

% tufte \@caption doesn't invoke the hyperref bits.
% The fix is two parts, one to set up the type and
% one to provide the anchor.  It takes two patches
% to put this in...
\pretocmd{\@caption}%
  {\expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
                    \csname iftrue\endcsname
      \global\let\@currentHref\hc@currentHref
    \else
      \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
    \fi
    \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{%
      \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
    }{%
      \NR@gettitle{#2}%
    }%
  }
  {\typeout{patched captioning, part 1}}% success msg
  {\typeout{HELP - failed to patch captioning, part 1}}% fail msg
\patchcmd{\@caption}%
  {\ignorespaces#3\par}% search
  {\ignorespaces
   \ifHy@nesting
     \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{\@currentHref}{#3}%
   \else
     \Hy@raisedlink{%
       \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{%
         \@currentHref
       }{\relax}%
     }%
     #3\fi\par}% replace
  {\typeout{patched captioning, part 2}}% success msg
  {\typeout{HELP - failed to patch captioning, part 2}}% fail msg
```

I don't properly understand all the hyperref code in the first place: I cobbled this together by comparing the internal definitions of `\@caption` in the two files (`hyperref.sty` and `tufte-common.def`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work well with `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures} % cleveref by default has `fig.'
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Testchapter}

\section{Testsection}
\label{sec:test}

\begin{figure}
    \rule{20pt}{20pt}
    \caption{Testfigure}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

Cross reference to \cref{fig:test}
and to \cref{sec:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]